# Let $X=\mathbb R$ with cofinite topology and $A=[0,1]$ with subspace topology - show $A$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the cofinite topology and $A=[0,1]$ with the subspace topology. I've just proven that every closed subspace of a compact space is compact, and now I'm asked to show that $A$ is compact, but not a closed subset of $X$. (I've shown this second part.)

I know that $\mathbb R$ is compact when given the cofinite topology, so to show $A$ is compact I need to show it is a closed subspace of $X$, but I'm not really sure what the distinction is between closed subspace and closed subset. I know that the open sets in the subspace topology consist of $U=V\cap A$ for $V$ open in $X$, so do I just need to show that $[0,1]$ cannot be written in this form?

Suppose it can be written as $[0,1]=V\cap [0,1]$ for some $V$ open in $X$, so $V=\mathbb R\backslash\{x_1,...,x_k\}$. That would mean that $\mathbb R\backslash\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subset [0,1]$ which is clearly false, so $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$. (I only worked this out while asking the question so basically asking if this is correct now)

EDIT: Just realised this doesn't imply $\mathbb R\backslash\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subset [0,1]$ but actually that $[0,1]\subset \mathbb R\backslash\{x_1,...,x_k\}$, which doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: This won't work: The only proper closed sets in the co-finite topology on $\mathbb R$ are finite (because all the open sets have finite compliment). It's still true that A is compact; but compact sets needn't be closed in a non-Hausdorff space

Comment: I've already shown it is not a closed subset of $X$, but the way the questions are ordered implies I have to show that it is a closed 'subspace', so my question is basically are these the same thing? It's the wording of the question I don't really understand

Comment: If you know how to show $\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology is compact, you could run the same argument to show $A$ is compact as a subspace.

Comment: @Loobear23 I think you might have misunderstood the ordering. The question might just want you to show that being a closed subspace of a compact space is a sufficient but not necessary condition for compactness. Hence, $A$ serves as a counterexample, an open set that is compact.

Comment: I see. I thought I was meant to show that $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$, but not a closed subset, which made me doubt they were the same thing. So they are the same thing?

Comment: $A \subset X$ by definition is a subset. It is closed if its complement is open. If $A$ is closed and is given the subspace topology, then we say $A$ is a closed subspace. So strictly speaking, they are not the same thing. But since any subset can be given the subspace topology, they are kind of the same thing.

Comment: @Loobear23 They are very much the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just running with the definition works. First, we see that the non-empty open sets in $A$ are sets with finite compliment in $A$. Now say $\{ U_\alpha \}$ is an open cover of $A$. Let consider some $U_0$. It's compliment in $A$ is a finite set $\{a_1, a_2, \dots a_n \}$. Pick $U_i$ from the open cover such that it covers $a_i$. We thus have a finite subcover $\{ U_0, U_1, U_2, \dots U_n \} $.

Comment: @Loobear23 Indeed. And that proves that $[0,1]\setminus U$ must be finite as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you seem to be misunderstanding:

1. If $X$ is a compact space and $A\subseteq X$ is closed, then $A$ is compact with the subspace topology, but for the converse to be true, $X$ needs to be Hausdorff, which is not true in your case. (In fact, it is not difficult to show that if $X$ is any topological space, then you can find $X'\supsetneq X$ in which $X$ is not closed, which is compact and $T_1$ as long as $X$ is.)
2. As you have seen yourself, in your case, $A$ is *not* a closed subspace of $X$, and $X$ is clearly not Hausdorff, so the above criterion is not helpful at all. So no, you don't *need* to show that $A$ is closed in $X$.
3. What you can do is just check directly that $A$ is not an essentially infinite union of open subsets of $A$, that is, there is no infinite family $\mathcal A$ of open subsets of $A$ (*in the subspace topology*) such that $\bigcup \mathcal A=A$ and the union of every finite subfamily of $\mathcal A$ is a proper subset of $A$.
4. $U$ is an open subset of $A$ in the subspace topology when $U=V\cap A$ for some $V\subseteq X$ open, not when $U=V\subseteq A$ for some $V\subseteq X$ open (unless $A$ itself happens to be open, in which case the two definitions coincide).
5. In this case, it is not hard to see that if $X$ is any space with the cofinite topology and $A\subseteq X$, then the subspace topology is still the cofinite topology. The cofinite topology is always compact, so $A$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, it's true that a closed subset of a compact topological space is itself compact, but it's not true at all that a compact subset of a topological space is always closed.In fact, it holds if the parent space is Hausdorff, which is clearly not the case here.So there is no contradiction at all.In your argument you tried to show that $A$ is closed, which it's definitely not, but still it happens to be compact.There is no contradiction here, because in non-Hausdorff spaces, a compact subset might not necessarily be closed, even though a closed subset of a compact topological space is always compact, Hausdorff or not.Try proving that a compact subset of a topological space is closed, and you will see that you require the Hausdorff property.Your argument is actually a good example of the failure of this conclusion.